# Как присвоить переменной значения из БД?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица films -> name -> Фильмец (просто название)

Допустим я хочу задать это в переменную `$test`.

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($connectdb, "SELECT `name`  FROM films WHERE name='film_name'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$test = $row['name'];
```

или

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name`  FROM films WHERE name='film_name'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$test = $row['name'];
```

или вместо fetch_assoc() можно использовать fetch_row

```
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$test = $row[0]; //нужно указать индекс столбца name
```

Comment: А зачем нужно  WHERE name='film_name' ?

Comment: чтобы выбрать тот фильм который вам нужен. В БД может быть много фильмов, если вам нужен конкретный фильм вместо film_name ставиться название фильма

Comment: Дело в том, что я пытаюсь вывести название фильма в title на странице и почему-то не получается.

Comment: так смотрите можете делать вот так, сейчас напишу отправлю

Comment: `<?php 
   $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name  FROM films WHERE name='film_name'");
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $test = $row['name'];
   ?>
   
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $test ?></title>
    </head>
</html>`

Comment: $result = $connection->query("SELECT name FROM films WHERE name='film_name'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $test = $row['name'];
$title = $test; $connection - подключение к бд. Переменной переменная title должна принимать значение названия страницы. Почему-то ничего не происходит.

Comment: вы можете сразу в переменную $title присвоить значение $row['name'], не используя переменную $test

Comment: вметсо film_name ставьте имя фильма в вашей БД

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: обращайтесь, всегда рад помочь ;D